# didExitRegion not fired when turn off bluetooth

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, core-location, ibeacon

Im building a simple ios app with `IBeacon`, I'm monitoring a region but I have some issues with enter and exit events.

If I go into a region the callback `didEnterRegion` is fired, but being within the region, turning off bluetooth doesn't fire `didExitRegion` callback. Is this the expected behavior?

This is an issue since I have to be able to detect when the user exits the region. Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried implementing `didDetermineState` as well as the didEnter/Exit? The latter will only happen when the state changes from "outside" to "inside" and vice versa. Chance is that disabling Bluetooth pushes the state into "unknown", so when later you enable Bluetooth outside the region, it won't trigger the exit. It should, however, trigger a state change, and a call do `didDetermineState`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For testing purposes you must turn off your beacons or move out of range to get a `didExitRegion` event.

Once `CoreLocation` has determined it is inside a `CLBeaconRegion` it will only change state to being outside the region after it has a chance to do a Bluetooth scan for 3 seconds during which time no beacons matching the `CLBeaconRegion` are detected.  If Bluetooth is not on, it cannot scan to make this determination.

If you want to force an exit in your app in this case, consider listening for `CoreBluetooth` lifecycle events.  On power off, you can deregister each `CLBeaconRegion`, fire your `didExitRegion` logic manually, then deregister them with `CoreLocation`.

Comment: If I enable the "Uses Bluetooth LE Accessories" background capability, would "centralManagerDidUpdateState:" wake the app up in the background?

Comment: I do not believe so, no.  That is a foreground only callback.

Comment: @davidgyound Yeah, that's what I thought. Gave it a shot anyway and it seems to be working (presenting a UILocalNotification when I get the callback). At least after waiting long enough for the app to terminate, but not if the user explicitly killed the app in the multitasking window. I seem to remember that iOS used to prevent certain BLE activity if the user explicitly killed the app. Is that still the case? If so, do you know of a way to terminate an application "gracefully" so that I can test this? Thanks!

Comment: You can reboot... But I suspect that will not work.  You might also try using Google Maps and doing a lot of panning and zooming.  It eats memory and can cause the OS to evict other apps.