# Why is didExitRegion not called?

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

This is a followup from question [didEnterRegion not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43780765/why-is-my-didenterregion-delegate-not-called?noredirect=1#comment74603703_43780765)

please note it is not a duplicate of [didExitRegion not called when powered off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30640270/didexitregion-not-fired-when-turn-off-bluetooth)

The current problem is that didExitRegion is never called and it should be when the beacon is turned off.

I turn off the beacon and I can see the debugs telling me that didRangeBeacons starts giving me NULL values as expected, but no matter how long I wait didExitRegion is never called.

Below is my relevant code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    // Initialize location manager and set ourselves as the delegate
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;

    [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];

    // Create a NSUUID with the same UUID as the broadcasting beacon
    NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"39876A4B-43B2-4BE8-9A9C-41BAE913D56A"];

    // Setup a new region with that UUID and same identifier as the broadcasting beacon
    self.myBeaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uuid
                                                             identifier:@"me.netwizards.office"];

    // Tell location manager to start monitoring for the beacon region
    [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:self.myBeaconRegion];
    NSLog(@"location Manager started to monitor regions: %@", self.locationManager.monitoredRegions);
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Error : %@",error);
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager monitoringDidFailForRegion:(CLRegion *)region withError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Region monitoring failed with error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion*)region
{
    NSLog(@"Did Enter Region");
    [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.myBeaconRegion];
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion*)region
{
    [self.locationManager stopRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.myBeaconRegion];
    self.viewControllerStoreLbl.text = @"No Store Detected";
    NSLog(@"Did Exit Region");
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager
       didRangeBeacons:(NSArray*)beacons
              inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion*)region
{
    // Beacon found!
    self.viewControllerStoreLbl.text = @"Matts Test Store";

    CLBeacon *foundBeacon = [beacons firstObject];

    // You can retrieve the beacon data from its properties
    NSString *uuid = foundBeacon.proximityUUID.UUIDString;
    NSString *major = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", foundBeacon.major];
    NSString *minor = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", foundBeacon.minor];

    NSLog(@"Beacon Data: UUID: %@, major: %@, minor: %@", uuid, major, minor);
}
```

Why is didExitRegion never called when beacon is turned off?

Comment: Does it getting call when beacon is turned on and device goes out of its range?

Comment: Yes it does get called if the beacon is on and goes out of range but how can it know the difference between out of range and transmitter turned off?

Comment: yes you are right...technically it should work...Are you using EstimoteSDK?

Comment: no SDK just plain XCODE stuff and even more weird if my transmitter goes to sleep mode then it called didExitRegion so it seems as long as the transmitter is reachable via bluetooth even though its not broadcasting didExitRegion is never called, has anyone seen this before?

Comment: did you try this self.beaconRegion.notifyOnExit=YES;
 ?

Comment: @KKRocks where would that go exactly ?

Comment: you need to add this in ViewDidLaod .

Comment: @KKRocks ok that seems to work on limited testing, but what is the purpose of that command? I tried googling but found no good answer

Comment: see this : https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/clregion/1423595-notifyonexit?language=objc

Comment: ok but the default value is YES so why is it needed at all?

Comment: this simply does not work reliable, it works sometimes, I refactored the code to catch the auth state as well of the locationManager to avoid first start problem with the synch locationauthstate call but the problem remains the same didEnterRegion is not called reliably